# How do I create formula to change cell colour if text is found in range

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a number of lists (on separate tabs) which I am trying to put into a formula. When an address is filled in on my spreadsheet I want it to check which of the background tabs the street name appears in & mark it as a colour depending on which tab.

```
Arkindale Road
Ballamore Road             DW            Blue
Bankfoot Road
Battersby Road

Abbotswell Road
Algernon Road              LT            Green
Algiers Road
Amyruth Road
```

If Ballamore Road is input, it is found on tab called DW then I want that cell (or preferably row) to change colour to blue.

Comment: This will require VBA. What have you tried already? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Will conditional formatting work for you?  I am pretty sure it can do what you need.  I am no pro on it though, hence no answer.  We have used it and it works great to change colors and such based on conditions.

Comment: Unfortunately conditional formatting will not pick up from a range.  I have tried creating a formula to state the name of the tab which i would then use for conditional formatting but I can only get this to work for one tab. Once I start to add more tabs it ignores them & returns the first tab name even though that address does not appear in the first tab. I have tried match, counta & if but am having no luck